# Meaning of 'a round of golf (or ten)'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The end is near for the president. But a round of golf **(or ten)**, a wedding toast, and a few bizarre press conferences come first.

The news report is [here](https://www.thedailybeast.com/the-end-of-the-line-for-trumpland-is-a-poorly-rated-sex-shop-in-north-philly).

What does 'or ten' mean?

Is it or are they 'a round of golf or ten rounds of golf'? Does it mean many rounds of golf due to his losing job and long lasting free time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"A *thing* or ten" is an expression suggesting a lot of something. It's a humorous mutation of the expression "a *thing* or two".

> Would you like to have a beer or two?

This is an invitation to drink one or maybe a small number of beers.

> Would you like to have a beer or ten?

This is a humorous invitation to drink a lot of beers.

Comment: It is a phrase that plays with the expectation of the listener. When spoken, one would often insert a pause to further misdirect the listener into thinking the sentence is over: "Would you like to have a beer … or ten?"

Answer (score 6):

A typical expression meaning "more than one" is, from [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one+or+two)

> **one or two**
> A small number; a few; a trivial or insignificant amount.
> *There have been one or two issues since we started operation, but overall everything has gone smoothly.*

Here, the expression "one (or ten)" does not mean actually 10 rounds of golf, but is a reference to the fact that Mr Trump plays a lot of golf.

[*The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/nov/07/donald-trump-golf-course-joe-biden-election) says

> Trump’s dedication to playing golf while in office has been a source of continuing controversy – particularly because he memorably and repeatedly lambasted his predecessor, Barack Obama, over how often he played the game.

So the report is referring to Mr Trump's love of golf (he owns many courses) and remarks that he is having quite a lot of down time.

<sub>Side note: He is not yet out of a job or have time on his hands, but he probably needs a rest after the intense campaigning.</sub>